# Prove that $a_{n}=\frac{b}{2a+a_{n-1}}$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

For any positive integer numbers $a$ and $b$ consider the sequence:
\begin{eqnarray}
 a_{1}=a \hspace{0.5cm} a_{n}=\frac{b}{2a+a_{n-1}}
\end{eqnarray}
For $n\geq 2$. I need to prove this sequence is convergent, but if $a,b \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$ it is not always increasing, maybe I need to find a subsequence of this sequence, but it's hard to see a simple view, I don't know if I need to see the $\overline{\lim a_{n}}$ and $\underline{\lim a_{n}}$ where:
\begin{eqnarray}
 \overline{\lim a_{n}}&=&\sup_{k\geq n}\{a_{k}\}\\
 \underline{\lim a_{n}}&=&\inf_{k\geq n}\{a_{k}\}
\end{eqnarray}
If you can give me one advice or hint, I will be grateful, as I don't see some things. Thanks .

Comment: I would take a look at even and odd indexed terms if I were you. Not for nothing, but taking $x_n=\frac{a_n}{a}$ transforms your DE into $x_n=\frac{\gamma}{x_{n-1}+2}$ subject to $x_1=1$ where $\gamma=\frac{b}{a^2}$

Comment: The upper limit $\overline{\lim}_{n\to\infty} a_n$ is defined as $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_{k\geq n} a_k$ btw. Similarly for the lower limit.

Comment: "*not always increasing, maybe I need to find a subsequence of this sequence*" $\;-\;$ Hint: $\;\displaystyle a_{n+1}-a_n$ $\displaystyle =\frac{b}{2a+a_{n}} - \frac{b}{2a+a_{n-1}}$ $\displaystyle =\frac{-b\left(a_n-a_{n-1}\right)}{(2a+a_{n})(2a+a_{n-1})}$, so the difference between consecutive terms changes sign at each step. This suggests looking at the subsequences of odd and even indices, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1: Can you show that the sequence is bounded?

Hint 2: Can you look at the possible limits for any subsequence? Can you show that all subsequences have to converge to the same limit?

Answer (score 0):

If there is a limit, $L,$ it solves $L=\frac b{2a+L}.$ Solve for $L.$ (There are two solutions for $L,$ but one of them is negative, so you can ignore that case.)

Then relate $|a_n-L|$ in terms to $|a_{n-1}-L|.$ Use that to show $|a_n-L|\to 0.$